# Save Alert-textfieldinput in Swift

Tags: swift, textfield

I want to have a table view, where you can add a new element when you click on the last cell. I can't find out, how I save whats put in the textfield, after you click "ok".

As you can probably see from my code, I'm very new to programming and it is likely way to complicated. It would be super cool, if someone could help me out.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var companyTableView: UITableView!

var psgTextField: UITextField?
var emTextField: UITextField?


var passengers = [""]
var button: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureButton()

    companyTableView.delegate = self
    companyTableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return passengers.count
}


@objc func buttonTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter name and email",
                                            message: nil,
                                            preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: psgTextField)
    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: emTextField)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default, handler: self.okHandler)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true)


}

func psgTextField(textField: UITextField!) {
    psgTextField = textField
    psgTextField?.placeholder = "Name"
}

func emTextField(textField: UITextField!) {
    emTextField = textField
    emTextField?.placeholder = "Email"
}

func okHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!) {

    let psgStr = (psgTextField?.text)!

    passengers.removeLast()
    passengers.append(psgStr)
    passengers.append("")

}

func configureButton() {
    button = UILabel()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 300, height: 30)
    button?.frame = frame
    button?.text = "            Add Passenger"
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)))
    button?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    button?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let passenger = passengers[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = companyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") {
        cell.textLabel?.text = passenger

        if cell.textLabel?.text == "" {
            cell.contentView.addSubview(button!)
        } else {
            // Nothing
        }

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()


}
}
```

When I now click on "Submit", the alert just goes of and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `companyTableView.reloadData()` in your `okHandler` method.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot now it works. It may not seems like it, but I really did research what the problem is.... Anyway, thank you :D

Comment: @Robin Of course as soon as you restart your app, all the data will be gone again. But that's another issue to solve.

Comment: That actually isn't that important. When you restart the app you need a new table